# Expose Expressjs middleware in API Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on an Nodejs API Client that takes this simple form:

```
//client.js
function Client (appId, token) {

    if (!(this instanceof Client)) {
        return new Client(appId, token);
    }

    this._appId = appId;
    this._token = token;
    ...
}

Client.prototype.save = function (data,callback) {
    return this_request(...);
}

Client.prototype._request = function (method, url, data, callback) {
    //do stuff
}

module.exports = Client
```

I would now like to make an `auth` function available as middleware in Expressjs routes but I'm not sure how to integrate the function into `client.js`.

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var thingy = myModule("12345", 'abcde');

router.get('/protectedRoute', thingy.auth, function(req, res, next){

}
```

For example, should the function be defined as part of the `prototype` like this:

```
Client.prototype.auth = function(req,res,next) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Any pointers and recommendations much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the way middleware is implemented, is that you have to pass a function for it to then get called with `req` `res` and `next`. As you've taken the OOP approach and made `auth` a prototype method on an object, when that function gets called by express, it will have a different `this` scope, and would thus likely throw an error. You need to use `bind` to create a function that binds a specific scope to that function, and then pass that to express.

```
router.get('/protectedRoute', thingy.auth.bind(thingy), function(req, res, next){

}
```

Alternatively:

```
var authMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  thingy.auth(req,  res, next);
}

router.get('/protectedRoute', authMiddleware, function(req, res, next){

}
```